# installing ubuntu 14.10 on usb-stick with hardware write protection

Tags: usb

Will ubuntu run faultless after being installed on a usb-device (memorystick) and when write protection switch of this device is being enabled after system setup?

What is going to happen with all the system log- and temp-files? Will they be managed automatically or do I need to modify any system settings?

How do I have to modify ubuntu thus the system can run from a usb device with write protection switch enabled?

Comment: Is this a live media usb you want to use, or a full install?

Comment: I meant a full install.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a full install, it won't work (write failure).

If it's the install-USB (live CD on USB), then no problem. It was designed that way. All changes are made in ram.

Comment: I do't get it. I can point all the tmp and log files to a writeable volume - can't I? Not possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of files which get written on the root filesystem you will have to track down:

```
sudo find / -newer <some file from yesterday> -print
```

Then figure out which need to be replaced links to a file in /tmp, which you can set up in /tmp from a script you run from /etc/rc.local.  Of course, you have the known directories like /tmp and /var/log which you can put into a ramdisk mounted from /etc/ftab, So if you want to do some work, it should be possible.  Much easier to have a live media which you can select at boot time to have or not have persistence.